# How to extract values from struct data type in Informatica BDM object?

Tags: informatica

I have an Object created in Informatica BDM which has a `struct` data type port like below

[image]

Here is how the sruct column is made up of

```
filter_column struct<name:string, value:string, data_type:string>
```

I wanted to extract the name from the `filter_column` port and created an Expression. Then I created an out put port as shown in the below image.

[image]

In the Expression part I am trying to extract the `name` element

[image]

But I get the above error.

[image]

Anyone knows how to extract the elements from the Struct?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Alex you need extract the struct column. You can do right click on the source data object and check hierarchical conversions-> extract from complex ports.

Try this and let me know if that helps!
Also there is one video for your reference..

https://network.informatica.com/videos/2829